# Upgrading RAM/HDD in latest MBP

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation, warranty

I planning to buy a 13 inch MBP this month. Is it a good idea to stick to the standard 4GB of ram and 500GB harddrive, and upgrade it myself to 8GB/1TB? This would save me about $350. I have experience opening/repairing laptops, but I never had a MBP.. would this void my warranty?

Comment: Not that this should deter you, but just so that you know; the machine's warranty will not cover these aftermarket upgrades. If either of those parts fail, it's down to you to get them replaced under their own respective warranties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's an excellent idea. Apple clearly overprices hardware upgrades. 
And don't worry, it's super-easy to do (be sure to buy a Philips #00 and a T6 torx screwdriver) and it **doesn't void** your warranty! 
for detailed step-by-step guides you can go to ifixit.com .

Comment: Thanks, even with the extra screwdrivers I'll end up much cheaper!